# how to use multiple And condition where I combined three tables using inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join, operator-keyword

```
SELECT z.name, a.name, a.type, a.gender,
(
    SELECT
    COUNT(a.type)
    FROM animal a
 )
FROM zoo z
INNER JOIN zoo_animal_map m 
ON z.id = m.zoo_id
INNER JOIN animal a 
ON a.id = m.animal_id
WHERE a.type="Tiger" AND a.type ="Elephant" AND a.type =" Leopard";
```

Comment: Does this not work?

Comment: it is creating a table with empty values

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `IN`

```
SELECT 
  zoo.name   AS zoo_name
, ani.type   AS animal_type
, ani.gender AS animal_gender
, ani.name   AS animal_name
FROM zoo_animal_map AS map
JOIN zoo AS zoo
  ON zoo.id = map.zoo_id
JOIN animal AS ani 
  ON ani.id = map.animal_id
WHERE ani.type IN ('Tiger', 'Elephant', 'Leopard')
ORDER BY zoo.name, ani.type, ani.gender, ani.name
```

There are no animals that are both tiger AND elephant.
Not sure about the leophants though.

But if you want to find the zoo's that have all 3 types?
Then grouping by zoo, with conditional aggregation might work for you.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      map.zoo_id
    , zoo.name AS zoo_name
    , COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN ani.type = 'Tiger'
            THEN ani.id
            END) AS Tigers
    , COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN ani.type = 'Elephant'
            THEN ani.id
            END) AS Elephants
    , COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN ani.type = 'Leopard'
            THEN ani.id
            END) AS Leopards
    , COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN ani.type = 'Tiger' 
             AND ani.gender LIKE 'F%' 
            THEN ani.id
            END) AS FemaleTigers
    , COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN ani.type = 'Elephant' 
             AND ani.gender LIKE 'F%' 
            THEN ani.id
            END) AS FemaleElephants
    , COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN ani.type = 'Leopard'
             AND ani.gender LIKE 'F%' 
            THEN ani.id
            END) AS FemaleLeopards
    , COUNT(DISTINCT ani.type) AS AnimalTypes
    FROM zoo_animal_map AS map
    JOIN zoo AS zoo
      ON zoo.id = map.zoo_id
    JOIN animal AS ani 
      ON ani.id = map.animal_id
    GROUP BY map.zoo_id, zoo.name
) AS zoos
WHERE Tigers > 0
  AND Elephants > 0
  AND Leopards > 0
ORDER BY zoo_name
```

| zoo_name | animal_type | animal_gender | animal_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| The Wild Zoo | Elephant | Male | adam |
| The Wild Zoo | Leopard | Male | allen |
| The Wild Zoo | Tiger | Female | nancy |
| The Wild Zoo | Tiger | Male | tommy |

| zoo_id | zoo_name | Tigers | Elephants | Leopards | FemaleTigers | FemaleElephants | FemaleLeopards | AnimalTypes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | The Wild Zoo | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8566f6797f188065fdcbe0e6d87937e2)*

Comment: thanks it displays now value of count of each animal as value 1

Comment: in my table animal, in type column I have mentioned tiger twice so it should give output of count as 2 for tiger, 1 for elephant and 1 for leopard. Am I right?

Comment: the query i have to write is Display a list of all zoos that have elephants,tigers and leopards.

Comment: Without sample data I'm not sure what you expect. The count will be based on what's grouped.

Comment: id  name  type       gender  ancestors_id no
1 tommy Tiger       Male       1                     5
2 cany     Lion       Male       2                     5
3 adam   Elephant Male      3                     5
4 nancy   Tiger       Female  4                     5
5 allen     Leopard  Male      5                     5

Comment: i have sent you the sample tble

Comment: @r23 I've added a demo

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to the joins, you have three AND conditions which are contradicting.
Just replace it with OR and it will work

Comment: but i have to display a query which is :-                                                                           
Display a list of all zoos that have elephants,tigers and leopards.

Comment: Think of each animal in your desired list- its not an elephant, tiger and leopard altogheter- its either elephant, tiger OR leopard

Comment: makes sense. if all the three animals belong to same zoo then it displays the table