# I want to count rows of two columns with different values

Tags: sql

I have two columns gender(values = 'Male' , 'Female')   and grade(values = 'senior officer' , 'Junior Officer') and the table name is employee. I want to count all Males who are senior officers and all Males who are junior officers, vise versa for all females. Below is my code

```
''' SELECT staff_gender, staff_grade COUNT(*) 
    FROM permanent_staff 
    WHERE staff_gender='Female' AND staff_grade='senior officer' '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate.

```
SELECT staff_gender, staff_grade
, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM permanent_staff
GROUP BY staff_gender, staff_grade
ORDER BY staff_gender, staff_grade
```

Comment: your sql statement returns Female because I'm using this sql statement in python. I think my example code is not the right way to go about this

Comment: This sql should return 4 rows.

Comment: it's correct. It returns 4 rows but I want to return only total males who are junior officers

Comment: That's different from what I understand from the question. But then just add a WHERE clause for the male juniors  between the FROM and the GROUP BY.

Comment: And maybe have a look at [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70299960/4003419) where I used conditional aggregation